# Table of Contents: Period after Roman Numeral IV - Reduce Spacing

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, roman-numerals

I'm pretty new to LaTeX. I am writing a dissertation and I'm trying to edit my table of contents. I use roman numerals for numbering parts.

Unfortunately in the table of contents, the spacing before the period after the roman numeral IV is too big (after 'IV' and '.' it is bigger than after 'I' and '.'). Does anybody know how to make it smaller without making it smaller before the other roman numerals (I, II and III) as well?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[]{titletoc}
\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\part}[display]{}{\partname\nobreakspace\thepart}{0mm}{}

\titlecontents{part}
[0cm]
{}
{\hfil\normalfont\large\bfseries 
\thecontentslabel\mdseries .\bfseries ~\hfil
\normalfont\large\bfseries}
{}
{\normalsize\dotfill\scriptsize\bfseries\thecontentspage}
[]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Part}
\part{Part}
\part{Part}
\part{Part}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi. I would tend to think that LaTeX follows correctly typographic rules on this one. Though I don't know what such a rule would be :)

Comment: The spacing between the period symbol and the symbol V is about the same as the spacing between the period symbol and the symbol I. Because the bottom of the symbol V is offset to the left compared to the rightmost part of the symbol V, you get this effect of the dot looking offset to the right. If there were boxes around each letter, the impression would vanish.

Comment: One more comment: of course you are allowed not to follow typographic rules if you don't like them. Be careful though, if your send your manuscript to an editor.

Comment: Basically it is up to the font whether to kern the V and the . so that the period is closer to the bottom of the V. If in your text you have `... said King George V.` what are you thinking about "fixing" that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the change of font between `\thecontentslabel` and `.` which means no kerning will be applied.

You could do something where you could measure the width of boxes containing `\bfseries\thecontentslabel.` and `\bfseries\thecontentslabel\kern0pt.` and use the difference in widths to manually kern between the part number and the period.

Comment: Hi @Don. I tried to run Ekim's code and compared to just typing "IV." in regular text and could not see a notable difference in the spacing.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It's not pretty, but it works.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[]{titletoc}
\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\part}[display]{}{\partname\nobreakspace\thepart}{0mm}{}

\titlecontents{part}
[0cm]
{}
{\hfil\normalfont\large\bfseries 
\thecontentslabel\mdseries .\bfseries ~\hfil
\normalfont\large\bfseries}
{}
{\normalsize\dotfill\scriptsize\bfseries\thecontentspage}
[]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Part}
\part{Part}
\part{Part}

\titlecontents{part}
[0cm]
{}
{\hfil\normalfont\large\bfseries 
\thecontentslabel\mdseries $\!$.\bfseries ~\hfil
\normalfont\large\bfseries}
{}
{\normalsize\dotfill\scriptsize\bfseries\thecontentspage}
[]

\part{Part}
\part{Part}

\titlecontents{part}
[0cm]
{}
{\hfil\normalfont\large\bfseries 
\thecontentslabel\mdseries .\bfseries ~\hfil
\normalfont\large\bfseries}
{}
{\normalsize\dotfill\scriptsize\bfseries\thecontentspage}
[]

\part{Part}

\end{document}
```